# Problems on setting ListView's item background color

Tags: android, background, android-listview, simpleadapter

I've a `ListView` and when the user clicks on one of its items I want that item to become blue. In order to do this, in the `onCreate()` method of the `ListView` activity, I've set a listener for the user clicks.

```
m_listFile=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);  
      m_listFile.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {  

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {  
                arg0.getChildAt(arg2).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);  
            }
});
```

Everything works fine for the first visible items, but when I scroll the list, I've a 
`NullPointerException` at `arg0.getChildAt(arg2).setBackgroundColor(...)`, even if the `arg2` value has the right item index position.

My `ListView` has a two lines item structure, when I load the `ListView` I use this adapter:

```
 SimpleAdapter sa = new SimpleAdapter(
            getApplicationContext(), 
            expsList, 
            R.layout.listelement, 
            new String[] { "screen_name","text" },
            new int[] { R.id.Name, R.id.Value}) {

      };

      m_listFile.setAdapter(sa);
```

I don't understand how to solve this problem. Can I get some help?

Comment: Do you use a custom adapter for your `ListView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extend `SimpleAdapter` like this:

```
private class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

        public MyAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data,
                int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView,   parent);
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK); //or whatever is your default color
              //if the position exists in that list the you must set the background to BLUE
          if(pos!=null){
            if (pos.contains(position)) {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
          }
            return v;
        }

    }
```

Then in your activity add a field like this:

```
//this will hold the cliked position of the ListView
ArrayList<Integer> pos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

and set the adapter:

```
sa = new MyAdapter(
            getApplicationContext(), 
            expsList, 
            R.layout.listelement, 
            new String[] { "screen_name","text" },
            new int[] { R.id.Name, R.id.Value}) {

      };
m_listFile.setAdapter(sa);
```

When you click the row:

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {  
                    // check before we add the position to the list of clicked positions if it isn't already set
                if (!pos.contains(position)) {
                pos.add(position); //add the position of the clicked row
            }
        sa.notifyDataSetChanged(); //notify the adapter of the change       
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the great delay...Thank you so much, It works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use

```
arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

instead of

```
arg0.getChildAt(arg2).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

it is what the Android Developer Reference says [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

Comment: @Vossi No he can't cast them. `getItemAtPosition()` returns the `data` associated with that row(for example if the adapter is supposed to show `Strings` then this method will return the `String` from that row) and not the row view.

Comment: argh ok... What is about `findViewById(arg3)` ?

Comment: @Vossi You cant use `findViewById()` because you have a smaller number of views in the list, it's those views that the `ListView` recycles and use.